# Facebook: List of friends that no longer appear in my news feed

Tags: facebook

For a few of my "friends" on Facebook I have set to not appear in my news feed. For some of them I would like to change that so that I can view them in my news feed again.

Is there a list of such friends, so that I can check each one individually? Otherwise I'd have to go through all my friends and check which are hidden, which would take a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the left sidebar, below your profile image, find this option -

[image]

Click `Edit Settings` and you'll see the list of friends you have hidden.